# What is the meaning of this icon in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, icons, simulink

I encountered following icon in a [Simulink tutorial](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/modeling-an-automatic-transmission-controller.html). What is its meaning? I can not click on it.
[image]

[Simulink 8.3, Matlab R2014a]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that signal logging is enabled for that signal:

[image]

For more details, see the Simulink documentation on [Configure a Signal for Logging](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/configuring-a-signal-for-signal-logging.html).